# Running multiple programs in parallel in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I want to run multiple programs in parallel in `Spyder`. How do I do it? I tried deactivating `Use a single instance` under `Preferences---Applications` but this didn't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You can open as many consoles as you want by going to the menu `Consoles > New console`. Then you can run different files on each one.